# When do I need to use mixer pre-init as oppsed to just mixer.init?

Tags: python, pygame, mixer, sdl-mixer

What is the difference between pygame.mixer init and pygame.mixer pre init?  I saw a tutorial and he used pre-init, but the explanation wasn't clear.  Should I just use mixer init, or do both?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `pygame.init()`, which initialize all imported Pygame modules, calls `pygame.mixer.init()` with its default arguments, because

> some platforms require the `pygame.mixer` to be initialized after the display modules have initialized.

as the [documentation states](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init).

To solve this problem and set proper default values for `frequency`, `channels` and `buffersize` you could call `pygame.mixer.pre_init()` to preset the default mixer init arguments before you call the `pygame.init()` toplevel function.